# Unable to establish connection with postgres by using ClusterIP service

Tags: node.js, postgresql, kubernetes, microservices, prisma

Can't reach database server at `postgres-srv`:`5432`
Please make sure your database server is running at `postgres-srv`:`5432`.

depl.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: postgres-config
  labels:
    app: postgres
data:
  POSTGRES_DB: postgresdb
  POSTGRES_USER: postgres
  POSTGRES_PASSWORD: root
---
kind: PersistentVolume
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: postgres-pv-volume
  labels:
    app: postgres
    type: local
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  capacity:
    storage: 5Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  hostPath:
    path: /var/lib/data
---
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: postgres-pv-claim
  labels:
    app: postgres
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 5Gi
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: postgres
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: postgres
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: postgres
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: postgres
          image: postgres:latest
          imagePullPolicy: "IfNotPresent"
          envFrom:
            - configMapRef:
                name: postgres-config
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /var/lib/postgresql/data
              name: postgredb
      volumes:
        - name: postgredb
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: postgres-pv-claim
```

Service:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: postgres-srv
spec:
  selector:
    app: postgres
  ports:
    - name: db
      protocol: TCP
      port: 5432
      targetPort: 5432
```

```
postgres-srv      ClusterIP   10.108.208.56    <none>        5432/TCP            4m59s
```

Connection Url:

```
DATABASE_URL="postgresql://postgres:root@postgres-srv:5432/postgresdb?schema=public"
```

[image]

Comment: Try with postgres-srv.default:5432

Comment: @Yayotrón thank you but same result: Can't reach database server at `postgres-srv.default`:`5432`

Comment: Could you show us your deployment configuration? deployment yaml and pod yaml

Comment: Ummm I just tried the same setup you pasted here in my cluster and I was able to connect to the database using psql cli. How are you trying to connect? From where? Is it another pod?

Comment: yes from different pod

Comment: Is this pod in the same namespace? Which mechanism are you using to establish the connection (psql cli/some postgres client)?

Comment: they are in the same name space, I am using prisma orm

Comment: Could you try with postgres-srv.default.svc.cluster.local:5432?

Comment: Can't reach database server at `postgres-srv.default.svc.cluster.local`:`5432`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232990/discussion-between-yayotron-and-lord).

Comment: An update on the progress: connection can now be established from other pods running psql cli, however it's still not working from Prisma ORM configuration.

Comment: Did you ever sort this out? In the same boat...